# Getting Headers from API

Tags: python, json

So I'm trying to scrape a table from this API: 
`https://api.pbpstats.com/get-wowy-combination-stats/nbaTeamId=1610612743&Season=201819&SeasonType=Playoffs&PlayerIds=203999,1627750,200794`

But I'm having trouble getting the headers as a nice list like `['Players On', 'Players Off', 'Minutes', 'NetRtg', 'OffRtg', 'DefRtg']` for my eventual dataframe because the headers are their own class and not part of the other class `results`.

My current code looks like:

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-wowy-combination-stats/nba?TeamId=1610612743&Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Playoffs&PlayerIds=203999,1627750,200794'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
# grab table
table = response.json()['results'][0]
#grab headers
headers = response.json()['headers']
```

And when I `print(headers)` I get `[{'field': 'On', 'label': 'Players On'}, {'field': 'Off', 'label': 'Players Off'}, {'field': 'Minutes', 'label': 'Minutes', 'type': 'number'}, {'field': 'NetRtg', 'label': 'NetRtg', 'type': 'decimal'}, {'field': 'OffRtg', 'label': 'OffRtg', 'type': 'decimal'}, {'field': 'DefRtg', 'label': 'DefRtg', 'type': 'decimal'}]`.

Is a good way to get these into a list like `['Players On', 'Players Off', 'Minutes', 'NetRtg', 'OffRtg', 'DefRtg']` so I can then create a dataframe?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, just take out all values with any key in a list, check my answer on how to do so! @dejsdukes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extract out all the values with a specific key out of the `headers` list
and make your dictionary

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-wowy-combination-stats/nba?TeamId=1610612743&Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Playoffs&PlayerIds=203999,1627750,200794'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
#grab table
table = response.json()['results'][0]

#grab headers
headers = response.json()['headers']

#Extracting all values with every key into a dictionary
results = {}
for header in headers:
    for k,v in header.items():
        results.setdefault(k,[])
        results[k].append(v)

#Remove duplicate elements from the list of values
results = {k:list(set(v)) for k,v in results.items()}
print(results)
```

The output will look like

```
{
'field': ['Minutes', 'Off', 'On', 'DefRtg', 'NetRtg', 'OffRtg'], 
'label': ['Minutes', 'DefRtg', 'Players On', 'NetRtg', 'OffRtg', 'Players Off'], 
'type': ['decimal', 'number']
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept my answer if it helped you :) And upvote if possible @dejsdukes

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension to iterate through should do the trick:

```
import requests


url = 'https://api.pbpstats.com/get-wowy-combination-stats/nba?TeamId=1610612743&Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Playoffs&PlayerIds=203999,1627750,200794'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
# grab table
table = response.json()['results'][0]
#grab headers
headers = response.json()['headers']

headers = [each['label'] for each in headers ]
```